# Does expand.grid always orders the result in the same way?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(engine = c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1003), 
                 failure = c(1, 2, 3, 4), week = c(7, 2, 1, 3))
```

I would like to create a table containing each combination of failures, so that the combinations contain one failure for each engine.

This I have done using a loop and the `expand.grid` function:

```
engines <- unique(df["engine"])
failure_list <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(engines)[1]){
    failure_temp <- df["failure"][(df["engine"] == toString(engines[i,1]))]
    failure_list <- c(list(failure_temp), failure_list)
}
failure_combinations <- data.frame(t(expand.grid(failure_list)))`
```

Finally, I would like to create a `week_combinations` data frame that would be similar to the `failure_combinations` data frame, but in which the failure number should be replaced with the corresponding week number from the df data frame. Can I do this by simply modifying my `expand.grid` loop so that it would look like this:

```
engines <- unique(df["engine"])
failure_list <- list()
week_list <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(engines)[1]){
    failure_temp <- df["failure"][(df["engine"] == toString(engines[i,1]))]
    failure_list <- c(list(failure_temp), failure_list)
    week_temp <- df["week"][(df["engine"] == toString(engines[i,1]))]
    week_list <- c(list(week_temp), week_list)
}
failure_combinations <- data.frame(t(expand.grid(failure_list)))
week_combinations <- data.frame(t(expand.grid(week_list)))`
```

Now, doing this I get these data frames:

failure_combinations

```
X1 X2
4  4
3  3
1  2
```

week_combinations

```
X1 X2
3  3
1  1
7  2
```

Seems to work fine, however the only thing that I am worried about is that the `expand.grid` function for some reason will order the columns in the `failure_combinations` and `week_combinations` data frames differently, i.e. that `failure_combinations$X1` will not correspond to `week_combinations$X1`. This is very important for me since I plan on using the `week_combinations` to check which `failure_combination` produces the most centralized time distribution.

I have done some checks and so far the order is always the same in both data frames, however, believing is not good enough, I need to know :)!

Comment: If you are concerned, you could always explicitly order the data after you process it.  I'd recommend `arrange` in package `plyr` for ordering data frames by one or more columns.

Comment: to ensure the same order of columns in two data.frames, you could pass the `colnames(df1)` as input to df2 e.g. `df2<-df2[,colnames(df1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Expand.grid seems to have a logical sort order with the first sequence sorted according the order of the specified sequence, then second sorted in specifed sequence and so on - this is the test I just ran to show this

```
#test expand.grid

a=seq(1,3,1)
b=seq(4,6,1)
c=seq(7,9,1)

abc<-expand.grid(A=a,B=b,C=c)
```

I found this right up front is a lot quicker then sorting a few million records by three or four keys!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you can find information about a function in the documentation, `?expand.grid` tells us

> The first factors vary fastest.

and later

> Conversion to a factor is done with levels in the order they occur in
>   the character vectors (and not alphabetically, as is most common when
>   converting to factors).